# Can i check if condition is true for all elements in a list on Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How can i check in if statement that condition is true for elements in a collection

```
fun main() {
    var control = 20
    val list = mutableListOf<Int>()
    for (i in 1..20)
        list.add(i)
    while (true) {
        control++
        if (control % list[0] == 0 && control % list[1] == 0)
    }
}
```

i only write 2 conditions for convenience

Comment: Please provide example input and output.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not sure if you want to check if the condition is true for ALL the elements, or you just want to know which ONE in particular is true, or if ANY are true.

In the first scenario, where we want to know if ALL of them

```
val list = (1..20).toList() //a bit easier to create the list this way
val result = list.all { control % it == 0 }
println(result) //will print true if all of the elements are true, and false if at least one is false
```

The second scenario we can do a simple .map, to know each one individually.

```
val list = (1..20).toList()
val result = list.map { control % it == 0 }
println(result) //will print a list of type (true, false, true, etc) depending on each element
```

And if we want to check if ANY are true, we can do:

```
val list = (1..20).toList()
val result = list.any { control % it == 0 }
println(result) //will print true if any of the elements are true, and false if all of the elements are false
```

Edit since [Todd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49746/todd) mentioned `none` in the comments, I'll add a few other similar functions in case it would help others with similar questions.

Firstly, we don't actually need a list, all of these funcitons can work on the range directly (the ones above and the ones below)

```
val result = (1..20).all { it % 2 == 0 }
```

Other similar functions:

`none` - the opposite of `all`.

`filter` - will keep all elements for which the predicate is true.

`filterNot` - will keep all elements for which the predicate is false.

Comment: For completeness: `list.none { ... }` will tell you the oppsite of `all`.

Comment: Thanks first answer you gave was what i was looking for.

Comment: It really is worth getting to know the standard library, as it covers all sorts of common operations.

Answer (score 2):

Change my code to this if anyone interested

```
fun main() {
    var count = 20
    var flag = false
    val list = (1..20).toList()
    while (true){
        count++
        if (list.all { count % it == 0 }){
            println(count)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use [filter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-filtering.html):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val list = mutableListOf<Int>()

    for (i in 1..20)
        list.add(i)

    list.filter { it % 2 === 1 }
        .forEach { println(it) }
}
```